# What is the needed background to study Euler system?

Tags: elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

I'm interested in Euler system.I heated this theory was used to prove the finiteness of Tate-Shafarevich group of certain elliptic curves by rubin.

To read Karl Rubin's 'Euler system', what is the needed background to study this book if I suppose basic undergraduate knowledge and elliptic curve theory (Silverman's 'the arithmetic of elliptic curves')?

Comment: Basic undergrad knowledge + elliptic curves just isn't going to cut it. There are three steps to using Euler Systems to prove the finiteness of Sha. First, you need to construct an Euler system. Then, you need to show that the Euler system you have constructed is non-zero, assuming that some $L$ value doesn't vanish. Finally, you need to use the "Euler system machine" to use the existence of a non-vanishing Euler system to bound the size of certain Selmer groups....

Comment: Rubin's book handles this last step, but the main result is a theorem that can probably be taken as a black box. On the other hand, the first two steps are each substantial in their own rights. And in principle, you can learn all this and completely ignore the Iwasawa theory in the background, but I'm not sure that's the best idea... If you want to learn about Euler systems, you could start with the Euler system of cyclotomic units. After that, Loeffler-Zerbes have some [notes](https://www.math.arizona.edu/~swc/aws/2018/2018LoefflerZerbesNotes.pdf) that will at least tell you where to start.

Comment: You mean, Rubin's book can be understood with undergrad knowledge +eliptic curves, and first two essential steps in the finiteness of sha is also understandable, even though Rubin's book doesn't deal with them.But whole theory of Euler system needs background of Iwasawa theory, right ?

Comment: The third step is mostly independent from the other two, and is far more general: it works for any Euler system, while the first two steps typically require new ideas for every new setting. No - I don't think undergrad+silverman is enough, even then, and each of the three steps has its own pre-requisites. But at the bare minimum, even just to understand what an Euler system is, you'll need some knowledge of Group/Galois cohomology (beyond Silverman) and Galois representations. Rather than starting with Rubin's book, I'd suggest starting with some lecture notes on the ES of cyclotomic units.